# What was the first mass production pickup?

Tags: truck, pick-up, history

I believe Henry Ford was essentially the father of the mass production car.  When was the pickup truck invented? Who created the first mass production pickup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some information from the [Trucker Report](http://www.thetruckersreport.com/trucking-timeline-vintage-and-antique-truck-guide/).

> Gottlieb Daimler invented “vehicle no. 42” in 1896. Many truck enthusiasts cite “vehicle no. 42,” a horseless wagon, as the first truck. Daimler’s invention had a 4 horsepower, 1.1 liter, 2 cylinder engine that supposedly hauled 3,300 pounds. Skeptics believe that Daimler over-exaggerated the payload potential of “vehicle no. 42.” Daimler invented a 10-horsepower truck that boasted a top speed of 7.5 miles per hour. These lackluster results rarely convinced businessmen, farmers, and ranchers to turn over their draft horses and wagon for a pickup truck. The earliest factory-built models entered the market during the early 1900s, including the King, Reo, Autocar, and the 20-horsepower Auto Wagon.
>
> After the introduction of mass-produced automobiles, people started to modify their vehicles for enhanced utility. These people stripped off the rear bodywork and mounted open-topped boxes that resembled the first step towards the modern pickup truck. Ford Motor Company capitalized on this concept with the Model-T by offering consumers the choice to add-on a bed. Ford started selling the complete factory-built Model-T Runabout with Pickup Body in 1925. In 1928, Ford introduced the Model-A, a robust alternative to the Model-T pickup truck. The Model-A pickup truck featured luxuries never seen before, such as an all steel cab and roll up windows.

It appears good ole Henry Ford had this locked up as well.